# Лёгкий компиллятор AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

Нужен лёгкий компллятор AS3 в плане веса. Гугл направляет только на родные адобовские просторы, весом в 800+ мб, которые скачать не выйдет (очень слабый интернет).

Может быть, есть что-то весом до 200 мб?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Компилятор в составе Flex SDK вроде только.

Flex SDK 3.6 тут - http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/?e=flex3sdk

120мб

300мб - 4.6 версия - http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex-sdk-download.html

Советую ставить сразу FlashDevelop, он сам скачает нужный SDK, плюс отличный редактор AS3, плюс сборка приложений для разных платформ, Android, iOS, Win, Mac, Web/Flash. Не уверен, что уложиться в 320мб, но 350 точно.

http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=11900

Comment: @ShockWave, спасибо, помогли)

Answer (score 1):

Если нужен только компилятор, то он без SDK работать не будет. А SDK размер порядка 350 MB. И также нужна программа-текстовый редактор для работы с проектами - FlashDevelop - размер 30 MB. Согласен с комментарием выше. Скачайте FlashDevelop.